# How to enable all kind of special leters in my web site

Tags: html

The question is how can i enable all kind of leters in my website in my html
for example i want use polish special leters ś,ą,ć
german:  ä, ö, ü and all kind of others

Comment: What have you tired? What's your websites encoding? So much questions to your question!

Comment: Check out [the first hit on Google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=special+characters+html)..

Comment: Yes, that was HTML5. Unicode, best multibyte UTF-8: `text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Answer (score 1):

Several approaches:

- First of all, the classic and most compatible approach: Use **HTML entities**. This a a special character sequence starting with `&` and ending with a `;`. The most common characters are named, for example the `ü` ("u umlaut") can be respresented using `&uuml;` in your HTML source. For the uppercase character you'd use `&Uuml;`. For unnamed characters, you can use `#` to denote Unicode characters, like `&#194;` (decimal) and `&#x00C2;` both representing `Â`.
- As an alternative, just save your HTML using UTF-8 and set the proper encoding in the HTML header. All modern browsers should display these just fine (e.g. `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` or the shorter variant `<meta charset="utf-8" />`).

Comment: so how do i set the proper encoding ? becous the string i display is not depending of me i get it from json it can be all kind of world language and for now it doesnt display special signs

Comment: Added tags to the second option.

Comment: What's the encoding your browser selected? For Internet Explorer this would be `View` > `Encoding`. You might have to clear your browser cache, then try again.

Comment: Are you sure the JSON you get is indeed UTF-8 as well? Or is it using some local codepage?

Comment: The HTML text file must also be UTF-8. A programmer's editor like [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) can play (set/show/change) with encodings.

Comment: i have no idea but still i parse it to my java class in my spring mvc application and display from there

Comment: Download the JSON file and save it to disk. Count the numbers of visible characters and the number of bytes in the file. A UTF-8 file typically has overhead 2 bytes plus (at least) one byte per non-ANSI character. Or open the file using some editor like the mentioned JEdit or Notepad++.

Comment: If JSON, Java, etc. is involved, the problem differs from the question asked. So please accept the correct answer, and post a new question if needed, wuith sufficient information to reconstruct the problem